# How do I remove a values from javaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var object = {
   'ex1': '123',
   'ex2': '234',
   'ex3': '345',
   'ex4': '456',
   'ex5': '678'
}
```

What is the best way to remove values without remove property as follows?

```
var object = {
   'ex1': '',
   'ex2': '',
   'ex3': '',
   'ex4': '',
   'ex5': ''
}
```

Comment: `for (const p in obj) obj[p] = '';`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the keys, iterate and assign a wanted value to the properties.

```js
var object = { ex1: '123', ex2: '234', ex3: '345', ex4: '456', ex5: '678' };

Object
    .keys(object)
    .forEach(k => object[k] = '');

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `for...in` to iterate over the object properties:

```js
var object = {
   'ex1': '123',
   'ex2': '234',
   'ex3': '345',
   'ex4': '456',
   'ex5': '678'
}

for (const prop in object) { object[prop] = '' };

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate though the object keys using `Object.keys` and set the values to empty. Also you need to name you object something other than `Object` since its already a predefined object in javascript.

```js
var object = {
   'ex1': '123',
   'ex2': '234',
   'ex3': '345',
   'ex4': '456',
   'ex5': '678'
}

Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
   object[key]  = ''
})
console.log(object);
```

Comment: `object` is not a good name for a variable, but it's perfectly legal.

Comment: @connexo It does prevent us from using `Object.keys` though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can reach it by using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

```js
var obj = {
   'ex1': '123',
   'ex2': '234',
   'ex3': '345',
   'ex4': '456',
   'ex5': '678'
}

const new_object = Object.keys(obj).reduce((agg, item) => {
  agg[item] = ''
  return agg
}, {})

console.log(new_object)
```

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
>   each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

**EDIT:**

Notice that reduce will return an new object (It will not override the existing object).

If you prefer to override the existing object, look at other answers who use the `forEach` loop.

Comment: This would not change references to the element.

Comment: Although it definitely works it creates a new object which might be desired but might not also be what the author wanted

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned this, I've added an Edit section.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are all many approaches.

**I like this one:**

```
    const obj = {
      ex1: '123',
      ex2: '234',
      ex3: '345',
      ex4: '456',
      ex5: '678'
    }

    for (const p in obj) obj[p] = null;

    console.log(obj);
```

**But I find also acceptable the one using ES6 iterators:**

```
    const obj1 = {
      ex1: '123',
      ex2: '234',
      ex3: '345',
      ex4: '456',
      ex5: '678'
    }

    for (k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1)) {
      obj1[k] = null;
    }

    console.log(obj1);
```